# JQuery validator .removeData('validator') throwing error

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I am have used the remove data method to remove validation from the page. This works but throws an error in the console window and crashes with IE8 (I'm being forced to develop to this browser...sad I know!).
Does anyone know how I can stop this error?

Here is my code to remove the validator:

```
 .removeData('validator')
```

Here is the error message from the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
```

Comment: Do you use console.log() at all in your full code?

Comment: No, I'm aware IE doesn't like it